# How do you find the contact info of a professor in a foreign country?

Tags: communication

I'd like to read the paper "New Fragments of the Ishvarapratyabhijna-vivriti"  by Yohei Kawajiri.  I can't seem to find it online, so I thought I'd contact the author and ask him for a copy.  But I can't seem to find his contact information; he's affiliated with Chikushi Jogakuen University, but most of their [website](http://www.chikushi.ac.jp/) is in Japanese, and can't be usefully navigated even with Google Translate.

So my question is, how does one find the contact information of a professor in a foreign country whose websites are in a foreign language?  I assume that it is possible, since academics collaborate across countries all the time.  But I'm not sure how.

Comment: Send a paper mail.

Comment: @scaaahu Haha, that sounds even more inconvenient than paying for an international call.  I don't even remember the last time I sent someone a physical letter.

Comment: If you insist on using e-mail, I can't help you. I don't understand what's wrong with the paper mail. I receive about at least five paper mails every month. Some of them are bills, though.

Comment: @scaaahu I receive bills in the mail too, but it's probably been about two decades since I've sent a physical letter.  In any case, sending a letter would require paying international postage, so if possible I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: In that case, you may simply be out of luck if you try to communicate with people in a country where physical mail is more prevalent. Remember, there is more than one possible route of development. Some countries may completely phase out physical mail in favour of electronic communication, while others translate everything surrounding physical mail into the digital world (e.g. by having stamps that can be bought online, downloaded as PDF, and printed onto the envelope at home), at least for certain types of communication. I can't tell to which category Japan belongs, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Japan's a technologically advanced country, I'm sure that this professor has an email address.  I'm just having trouble getting his email address from the website.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Germany is a technologically advanced country, as well (although, admittedly, the penchant to having all kinds of electronic gadgets in all areas of one's life is rather not as prevalent here as it seems to be in Japan ;) ). Yet, depending on what you are trying to achieve, sending a paper letter goes a long way compared to a forgettable e-mail that can be deleted with a single keypress.

Comment: In case you're still looking, the paper seems to be Chapter 4 in [**Utpaladeva, Philosopher of Recognition**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ISBN+13:+9788124608432%22&filter=0) edited by Raffaele Torella and Bettina Bäumer (2016) -- see the book's description by bookseller "Vedams eBooks (P) Ltd, New Delhi, India" [here](https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?bi=0&cm_sp=SearchF-_-sf-_-Results&ds=30&sortby=17&sts=t&tn=Utpaladeva%3A%20Philosopher%20of%20Recognition&vci=573945) for a list of chapters.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- **Use a general contact for the university**, either phone or email, and try to get specific contact information for the person.  I would expect most universities that deal with international students to be able to respond in English.  Try an international student office if you don't have luck with the main number (it doesn't matter too much that you reach the "right person"; as long as they are relatively helpful, they can probably easily access an internal directory for you).
- **See if the author has a profile on a professional networking site** such as LinkedIn or ResearchGate.
- **Try to contact co-authors** if there are any.
- **Use Google site search.**  e.g. `site:www.chikushi.ac.jp Yohei Kawajiri`. If there was something in English, but hard to navigate to, this would probably find it.  Also should work for non-English sites that use Latin characters.  It didn't work in this case, though.

Comment: I would assume (s)he's not working at the university anymore. All the links that pop up when searching are from 2014 and before.

Comment: Yes, I sent an email to international@chikushi-u.ac.jp a couple days ago.  Let's see if I get a reply.

Comment: For the record I never got a reply to my email.